# Symfony2 shared users across multiple apps

Tags: session, symfony, acl

I have multiple symfony2 applications which share common entities, but use different database settings. Each of these databases has tables `user`, `user_role` and `role`.

Here's the catch: I would like that user to be able to login to `app1` by visiting `www.myproject.com/app1/login` and after changing URL to `/app2/` to use existing token **ONLY** if identical user exists in `app2`'s database (same username, password and salt). *Currently it checks only for same username which is, you must agree, quite inconvenient...*

I can't really see when `refreshUser()` is being called... :-/

All apps use same `User` and `Role` entities and `UserRepository`.

Any help would be much appreciated!

**UserRepository:**

```
class UserRepository extends EntityRepository implements \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface{
    /** @var User */
    private $user;

    public function loadUserByUsername($username) {
        /** @var $Q \Doctrine\ORM\Query */
        $Q = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery('SELECT u FROM CommonsBundle:User u WHERE u.username = :username')
        ->setParameters(array(
            'username' => $username
        ));
        $user = $Q->getOneOrNullResult();
        if ( $user == null ){
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("");
        }
        return $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user) {
        return $this->loadUserByUsername($user->getUsername());
    }

    public function supportsClass($class) {
        return $class === 'CommonsBundle\Entity\User';
    }

    public function findById($id){
        return $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery('SELECT u FROM CommonsBundle:User u WHERE u.id = :id')
            ->setParameters(array(
            'id' => $id
            ))
            ->getOneOrNullResult();
    }
}
```

**User#equals(UserInterface):**

I know there is a prettier way to write this method but I will rewrite it after see this working :)

```
public function equals(UserInterface $user)
{
    if (!$user instanceof User) {
          return false;
    }
    if ($this->password !== $user->getPassword()) {
          return false;
    }

    if ($this->getSalt() !== $user->getSalt()) {
          return false;
    }

    if ($this->username !== $user->getUsername()) {
          return false;
    }

    return true;
```

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Your question made me think.** When using symfony2 security, you got one problem: Either a session is valid, meaning the user is authenticated as either anonymous or real user, or the session is invalid.

So, with this in mind, I don't see your approach working as you would like it, because let's say user1 logs in and is using app1. Now he switches to app2 and is not in the database, meaning he should not have access. What to do now? Invalidate the session? This would mean he has to log in again in app1.

If you would use subdomains, you could tie your session to that subdomain, but this would mean the user has to log in again for each application.

There is another problem: It seems like symfony2 stores the id of the user into the session, so without access to the app1 database, you cannot know what the password and the roles of the user in the app1 database are and cannot check for it.

I guess the security of symfony2 was simply not made for such behaviour. It expects the session to relate to the same user within your whole application.

**I don't think that symfony2 is the big problem here** but the overall handling with php. Let's think for one moment what I would suggest without symfony2:

When a user logs in, store user and roles into a specific array in the session, like:

```
user.app1 = array('username','password',array('role1','role2'))
```

Now, on each request to app1 I would check if user.app1 is in the session and read the roles from there. If not, I would check for user.app2, user.app3 and so on. If I find none, redirect to login. If I find one, I would query the database to find the user with the same username and compare the other values. If match, store everything into the database. If not, check next user from session.

I looked up the symfony [security reference](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html), and you got some extension points, so maybe you can work from there on. The `form_login` got a `success_handler`, so adding the array to the session as suggested above should be done there. The firewall itself has some parameters like `request_matcher` and `entry_point` which could be used to add additional checks like the ones I mentioned above. All are defined as services, so injecting the entity manager and the security context should be no problem.

I personally think the design itself is not optimal here and you might be better of refactoring your code to either use one user for all apps and different roles (remember that you can define many entity managers and use different databases) or even consolidating all databases and storing everything into one database, using acl to prevent users from viewing the "wrong" content.

Comment: Thanks boo! During the past several days I have being doing some research on this and after reading your answer I came to realize that I will have to give up on whole idea as I imagined it. However, you idea about using firewall service points is quite interesting and worth looking into. I will, probably, have to do a code refactoring sooner than later... after all Symfony official docs do not encourage  separate apps, but bundles instead. Anyway, thank you very much for such detailed explanation and very useful recommendations. :)