# Login to symfony from external website

Tags: symfony, authentication, fosuserbundle

I'm have two websites one developed with php and the second one with Symfony. In the first website I've a list of users and a login button when I click on it I send a post request with the id of the selected user in order to login into the Symfony websites.

When I check the response I can see that I'm logged in successfully into the website under Symfony but under a new session once I receive the response and get redirected to the Symfony website I find that I'm not logged in and I'm using the old session.

Comment: How do you send this POST request? With JS or PHP?

Comment: @dragoste With js (ajax)

Comment: You can't do that like this, because returned cookies (session id in this case) doesn't get saved in user's browser. That would be unsafe.

Comment: Please check this link it might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9672560/symfony2-shared-users-across-multiple-apps